# How to leave an empty open partition when installing, while still availing of whole disk encryption and LVM?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

my need is straightforward, instead of installing my ubuntu on the whole hard drive I would like to reserve some space for a partition for other stuff. Basically I would like to avail of all the cool things the default installation partitioning provides (encryption, LVM) but also reserve some empty space to avail for some files exchange and similar stuff, an unencrypted partition for downloaded documents and the like (the hard drive is going to be a usb external one).
Hopefully you will have good guidance for me!
An happy Christmas and new year to the whole community!

Comment: When installing use the __manual option__ to create partitions there you can reserve a portion of the HDD for what you are asking for.

Comment: You can also specify a specific mount point for a manually created partition from within the installer. Common mount locations for "reserved space" supported by the installer are `/home` and `/srv` other than choosing the manual partitioning options the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) still apply.

Comment: Thanks! I would not really expect such a quick reply, can you suggest what partitions to create? I have 500GB and would like to have e.g. 200 for the os partition encrypted and with LVM (including 16gb encrypted swap disk perhaps) and the reminder for this spare partition. I played with the options but could not really make a decision on what to set.